If defined var fails to prevent syntax error from sending output to an undefined var
Consider the following snippet of Batch Scripting. . .
The goal is to write output to 2 files if log is defined (a log file) - or to use arg 2 only (another log file).  I have successfully used this syntax in the past, (at least - from what I recall) but for some reason, this continuously fails and gives me the error output posted below the code.  What silly thing am I missing today?
@Echo Off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
 If defined log (
   Echo Log is defined.
   If not "%~4"=="Yes" (
     If "%~nx2"=="%logNam%" (
       <nul (set /p "lineout=!WO_Log1!!cr!!lf!")>>%log%
     ) else (
       <nul (set /p "lineout=!WO_Log1!!cr!!lf!")>>%log%
       <nul (set /p "lineout=!WO_Arg1!!cr!!lf!")>>"%~2"
     )
   ) else (
     >>%log% Echo(!WO_Log1!
     >>"%~2" Echo(!WO_Arg1!
   )
 ) else (
   Echo Log is NOT defined.
   Echo "%~2"
   If not "%~4"=="Yes" (
     <nul (set /p "lineout=!WO_Log1!!cr!!lf!")>>"%~2"
   ) else (
     2>&1 >>"%~2" Echo(!WO_Log1!
   )
 )


The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Users\foobar>       <nul (set /p "lineout=!WO_Log1!!cr!!lf!")>>


Am I mistaken, or should this line never have evaluated if the var log was never defined?  I have confirmed that removing any reference to %log% solves the problem, but it seems like it should NOT be an issue. . .  Do I need to first check for the inverse, and make the first condition as if NOT defined log instead?

Just tested the inverse of checking for if defined by setting it as if not defined and . . . it failed too.

I believe you should continue with your hazadous guesses.
I modified your original code to
 If "%~nx2"=="%logNam%" (
   <nul (set /p "lineout=!WOaLog1!!cr!!lf!")>>%log%
 ) else (
   <nul (set /p "lineout=!WObLog1!!cr!!lf!")>>%log%

Note WOaLog1, WObLog1 - and then c, etc for similar lines. This allowed me to determine which of the lines was generating the syntax error (and yes, surely the nature of the error could be displayed but isn't)
Target : WOaLog1
The parser would scan this line and replace any %var% with the value of that variable when the for is encountered. At that time, %log% is not set, or empty, so the parser sees
<nul (set /p "lineout=!WOaLog1!!cr!!lf!")>>

notices that there is no destination specified for the redirection and declares a syntax error (Microsoft:guess where...!)
Replace the %log% with "%log%" and re-run.
Target : WObLog1
Because the destination is now "", which may be non-sensical, but isn't empty.
Naturally, !var! is not PARSED as an empty string, since it may or may not be assigned at RUN-TIME.
So, as a matter of course, I'd always specify a redirect-to-file as quoted so that "Spaces in filenames can be.accommodated"
and I follow the mantra that the !var! form should only be used within a code block where var is being varied within that block.

Great method of clarifying!  For what it is worth, the %log% variable is set in this manner: set log="C:\users\foo\in case of path with spaces\logname.log" so that the var itself contains the necessary quotes. . .saves keystrokes over time (yeah, yeah, only a couple, but across potentially hundreds of uses, it adds up).  Had I used the same syntax as all the other methods (like "%~2") for example while leaving the double quotes out of the var itself, I suppose I would've come to the realization MUCH sooner.  I will reconsider how I implement this going forward!

My personal recommendation is to not quote values in variables - nor to include a terminal backslash or space. For me, having to dequote as necessary or remove the terminal character(s) as required appears far too often within a for loop where such operations can cause a problem. I find that building a string by explicitly including those characters as required is easier and more obvious visually. As ever, YMMV.

Long days will do this to a person. . .
I nearly religiously use the DelayedExpansion version of a variable almost everywhere I go (save the comments of 'But it can be so much slower') - The one var I almost never delay expansion of is the log var since I almost always set it at the beginning of a file. . .  The code below works fine. . . posting this as an answer, but the brownie points will go to those who can offer up the why this sample works and the initial sample does not.
If I had to hazard a guess, I would expect that DelayingExpansion using !var! over %var% tells the Command Interpreter to "Postpone the parsing of this variable until it's called" whereas %var% implicitly forces the interpreter to try and resolve the var to the contained data (nul in this case), and thus failing. . .?  (Essentially - the interpreter can ignore >>!var! since it's delaying the expansion to nul, but cannot ignore >>%var% since it is clearly, and immediately expanding to >>)
 @Echo Off
 
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
 
 If defined log (
   Echo Log is defined.
   If not "%~4"=="Yes" (
     If "%~nx2"=="!logNam!" (
       REM The line below switched %log% with !log!
       <nul (set /p "lineout=!WO_Log1!!cr!!lf!")>>!log!
     ) else (
       REM The line below switched %log% with !log!
       <nul (set /p "lineout=!WO_Log1!!cr!!lf!")>>!log!
       <nul (set /p "lineout=!WO_Arg1!!cr!!lf!")>>"%~2"
     )
   ) else (
     REM The line below switched %log% with !log!
     >>!log! Echo(!WO_Log1!
     >>"%~2" Echo(!WO_Arg1!
   )
 ) else (
   Echo Log is NOT defined.
   Echo "%~2"
   If not "%~4"=="Yes" (
     <nul (set /p "lineout=!WO_Log1!!cr!!lf!")>>"%~2"
   ) else (
     2>&1 >>"%~2" Echo(!WO_Log1!
   )
 )

